# System.IndexOutOfRangeExecption ERROR - C#

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I have just tried run some code with arrays and simple writeline, and I got ERROR of "System.IndexOutOfRangeExecption" and more lines in gibberish.

The code (simple):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      // מטרת התכנית היא למצוא את שמו של התלמיד על פי מקום הישיבה שלו, וההפך
        // נשתמש במערך בשם Places.

        string[,] places =  new string [3,3];
        places[0, 0] = "Me & Dori";
        places[0, 1] = "Me & Dori";
        places[0, 2] = "Me & Dori";
        places[0, 3] = "Me & Dori";
        places[1, 0] = "Me & Dori";
        places[1, 1] = "Me & Dori";
        places[1, 2] = "Me & Dori";
        places[1, 3] = "Me & Dori";
        places[2, 0] = "Me & Dori";
        places[2, 1] = "Me & Dori";
        places[2, 2] = "Me & Dori";
        places[2, 3] = "Me & Dori";
        places[3, 0] = "Me & Dori";
        places[3, 1] = "Me & Dori";
        places[3, 2] = "Me & Dori";
        places[3, 3] = "Me & Dori";

        Console.WriteLine(places[1, 3]);
    }
```

*I dont know C# well, still learning... so I guess its something I forget to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an array in C# like this:

```
string[,] places =  new string [3,3];
```

you have 9 elements in this array, the indexing starting from 0,0 and the last is 2,2

And when you try to address the element at 2,3 it will throw the `Exception`

```
places[2, 3] = "Me & Dori";
```

Answer (score 2):

The size of your array is 3x3, and since arrays are c# is 0-based, your array ends at 2,2.

You have to set your array to 4x4 for your code to work:

```
string[,] places =  new string [4,4];
```

Or you should remove the code setting the upper bounds.

Comment: @Omer: need more help? If not, since you are new, please don't forget to accept the answer you liked most.

Answer (score 1):

```
new String[3,3]
```

The 3 indicates the amount of dimensions. Arrays are 0-based. So you create three dimensions. 0, 1 and 2. You try to set values to the fourth dimension.

```
places[3, 0] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 1] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 2] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 3] = "Me & Dori";
```

This doesn't work because there is no fourth dimension. So delete these lines or use:

```
string[,] places =  new string [4,4];
```

Comment: To clarify the terminology, I might replace "dimensions" with "size" to avoid confusion.  Technically I'd describe the array as having *two dimensions* each of which has a *size* of three.

Answer (score 0):

Max indices of your array are `places[2, 2]`. You need `string[,] places = new string[4,4];` in order to use

```
places[0, 3] = "Me & Dori";
places[1, 3] = "Me & Dori";
places[2, 3] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 0] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 1] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 2] = "Me & Dori";
places[3, 3] = "Me & Dori";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a 3x3 array but trying to assign 4x4 data to it.  To fix your example change to this:

```
string[,] places =  new string [4,4];
```